# How can I 'dodge' the position of geom_point in ggplot2?

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 in R to make plots like the following ones:

[image]

The errorbars overlap with each other which look really messy.
How can I separate the errorbars for different indices?
I have used position="dodge" but it seems to be not working. 
Here is the main part of my code:

```
plot =  ggplot(data,aes(x=ntrunc,y=beta_best,group=ntrunc,colour=INDEX))
       +geom_point(aes(shape=detectable),na.rm=TRUE,position="dodge") 
        +geom_errorbar(aes(x=ntrunc,ymax=beta_high,ymin=beta_low),na.rm=TRUE,position="dodge")
```

Comment: Have you tried different values of "dodge"? For example something like that: `position = position_dodge(width = 0.90)`. See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5256758/2378656).

Comment: Thanks for your example. However, I have just tried different values of width and it still does't work.

Comment: It is difficult to come up with solutions without the original dataset. But one question I have: Why are your $x$-values and the "groups" the same? What is `ntrunc`? Shouldn't `group` be `INDEX`?

Comment: It works now after I changed group="INDEX". I think I have misunderstood the meaning of 'group'. Thanks @COOLSerdash

Answer (score 12):

The *group* should = *INDEX* instead of *ntrunc* in the aes.

```
plot =  ggplot(data, aes(x=ntrunc, y=beta_best, group=INDEX, colour=INDEX)) +
   geom_point(aes(shape=detectable), na.rm=TRUE, position="dodge") +
   geom_errorbar(aes(x=ntrunc, ymax=beta_high, ymin=beta_low), na.rm=TRUE, position="dodge")
```

The plot looks better now.

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me until I used `geom_point(aes(shape=detectable),na.rm=TRUE, position=position_dodge(width=0.3))`

Comment: It would be great to get an example data here because I cannot reproduce your result.

Comment: @Nova my guess is the answer was broken when `ggplot2` went from version `0.9.X` to `1.X` or `2.X`